# Solving Improper Rational Trig Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, spherical-coordinates, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve a problem that involves evaluating the integral

$$ \int_0^{\infty} rdr \int_0^{\pi} \frac{a\sin{(\theta)}^3 d\theta}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2ar\cos{(\theta)})^{3/2}}$$

Mathematica computes the answer to be 2, which reproduces the final answer in the textbook. I have tried evaluating the integral by using trigonometric identities and then substituting $u = \cos{\theta}$ and have also tried evaluating the corresponding contour integral but had no success.

Could any one explain how one goes about evaluating the integral?

(If it's necessary, you can assume $a>0$)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will provide an outline; you will need to fill in the details yourself.  The substitution
$$x = r^2 + a^2 - 2ar \cos \theta, \\ 
dx = 2ar \sin \theta \, d\theta, $$
yields

$$\begin{align}
f_a(r) &= \int_{\theta=0}^\pi \frac{a \sin^3 \theta \, d\theta}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2ar \cos \theta)^{3/2}} \, d\theta = \frac{4}{3} \begin{cases}a/r^3, & a < r \\ 1/a^2, & a \ge r. \end{cases}
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\int_{r=0}^\infty r f_a(r) \, dr = 2.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} rdr \int_0^{\pi} \frac{a\sin{(\theta)}^3 d\theta}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2ar\cos{(\theta)})^{3/2}}\overset{\cos\theta=x}{=}\int_0^{\infty} rdr \int_{-1}^1 \frac{a(1-x^2) dx}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2arx)^{3/2}}$$
$$=\int_0^ardr\int_{-1}^1 \frac{a(1-x^2) dx}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2arx)^{3/2}}+\int_a^\infty rdr\int_{-1}^1 \frac{a(1-x^2) dx}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2arx)^{3/2}}=I_{1{(r<a)}}+I_{2{(r>a)}}$$
$$I_1=\frac a{a^3}\int_0^ardr\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-x^2)dx}{\left((\frac ra)^2+1-2\frac rax\right)^{3/2}}\overset{t=\frac ra}{=}\int_0^1dt\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)\left(\frac d{dx}\frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}\right)dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\int_0^1dt\left(\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}\,\bigg|_{x=-1}^1\right)+2\int_0^1dt\int_{-1}^1\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{t^2-2tx+t^2}}$$
But $\displaystyle \frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}$ is the generating function for  [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$ \frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n,\,\,|t|<1$$
Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, and $P_1(x)=x$. Hence, at $r<a$
$$I_1=2\int_0^1dt\int_{-1}^1P_1(x)\cdot P_1(x)\,t\,dx=2\int_0^1tdt\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac23\tag{1}$$
In the same way, for the case $r>a$
$$I_2=a\int_a^\infty \frac{rdr}{r^3}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-x^2)dx}{\left((\frac ar)^2+1-2\frac arx\right)^{3/2}}\overset{t=\frac ar}{=}\int_0^1dt\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-x^2)dx}{(t^2+1-2tx)^{3/2}}$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{dt}t\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)\left(\frac d{dx}\frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}\right)dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}2\int_0^1\frac{dt}t\int_{-1}^1\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{t^2+1-2tx}}=2\int_0^1dt\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac43\tag{2}$$
$$I(a)=I_1+I_2=2$$
the result obtained by @heropup .

Answer (score 4):

$\def\th{\theta}$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} rdr \int_0^{\pi} 
\frac{a\sin^3\th \,d\th}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2ar\cos\th)^{3/2}}
&= \int_0^{\pi}  a\sin^3\th 
\int_0^{\infty} 
\frac{r}{(r^2 + a^2 - 2ar\cos\th)^{3/2}}
dr\,d\th
    & \textrm{can justify} \\
&= \int_0^{\pi} a\sin^3\th 
\int_0^{\infty} 
\frac{r}{(r-a\cos\th)^2 + a^2\sin^2\th)^{3/2}}
dr\,d\th \\
&= \int_0^{\pi} a\sin^3\th 
\int_{-a\cos\th}^{\infty} 
\frac{u+a\cos\th}{(u^2 + a^2\sin^2\th)^{3/2}}
du\,d\th 
    & u = r-a\cos\th \\
&= \ldots 
    & \textrm{standard trig sub} \\ 
&= \int_0^\pi
\left.\left(
\frac{\sin\th(u\cos\th-a\sin^2\th)}{\sqrt{u^2+a^2\sin^2\th}}
\right)\right|_{-a\cos\th}^\infty 
d\th \\
&= \int_0^\pi (1+\cos\th)\sin\th\,d \th \\
&= 2
\end{align*}